# Database Explorer does not show database and table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am a beginner to ASP .net MVC 3. I installed visual web developer 2010 Express. I am learning from online videos. I created a sports project and created all the models as mentioned in the video. But When I switch to Database Explorer I am not able to see the created database where in video It shows the tables. I tried to open a database connection from database explorer but at that it shows that .mdb file is already open. How can I see automatically created database tables in Database explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the database it won't be added there automatically. If it's already open then maybe you opened it with access or any other 3rd party tool? Just pick a correct provider and open the file. That works for me...

Comment: thank you. Hey, Do I need SQL server management studio for that?

Comment: No, you don't need SQL server management studio to be able to access database using server explorer in Visual Studio.